# 2 Collections - Concat

Tags: mongodb, collections, concatenation

Extensive research couldn't answer this question but i feel it's not a big thing:

I aggregate product data and differ at the filter stage, my output (exact *same* keys) goes into 2 collections.

I work exclusively in mongoshell.

I have only found manuals to bring 2 collections together - with different keys, in this situation i'd use mapReduce to bring them together.
what i want is more like classic concat - put all the objects from 2 collections into one.

Comment: What is wrong with using the map reduce framework? It can easily output the results to a collection.

Comment: I am not sure you got me right :)
mapReduce seems overkill, the collections are the result of a simple match condition before aggregation.
I only need stuff from a + stuff from b, keys are all the same

Answer (score 1):

Found a definite answer, exactly what i needed:

use this in mongoshell:
    db.source_collection.find().forEach(function(obj){
    db.target_collection.insert(obj)
    });

easy, quick, excellent solution!

src: https://wrtsprt.wordpress.com/2011/08/17/merging-collections-in-mongodb/